# Рекурсивная функция "молния"

Tags: php

Рисую молнию, 2 линии, из каждых краев выходит еще по две линии, из них по две линии и т.п. Для этого использую рекурсивную функцию МОЛНИЯ. После выполнения тела функции МОЛНИЯ вызывается 2 раза. Но второй раз она почему-то не срабатывает, подскажите, пожалуйста почему?

```
function molnia($k1)
    {
    global $i;
    if($i>=10)
        {
        return;
        }
    $i++;
    global $img,$c;
    $t['x']=$k1['x'];
    $t['y']=$k1['y'];
    $k2=$k1;
    $k1['x']+=rand(0,200);
    $k1['y']+=rand(0,200);
    $k2['x']+=rand(0,200);
    $k2['y']+=rand(0,200);
    imageline($img,$t['x'],$t['y'],$k1['x'],$k1['y'],$c);
    imageline($img,$t['x'],$t['y'],$k2['x'],$k2['y'],$c);
    $c=imagecolorallocate($img, rand(0,255), rand(0,255), rand(0,255));
    molnia($k1);
    molnia($k2);

    return;
    }

$k['x']=0;
$k['y']=0;
molnia($k);
```

Comment: На входе $i чему равно? Может не в рекурсии дело?

Comment: В том то и дело что дело в рекурсии, и неправильном описании параметров.

Answer (score 4):

Судя по логике, Ваша функция нарисует случайную кривую из 11-ти отрезков (если стартовое значение `$i=0`). То-есть, никакого графа с двумя линиями из последней точки не получится. Все потому, что счетчик `$i` дойдет до своего предела `10` в первом рекурсивном вызове. А так-как счетчик дошел до предела второй вызов споткнется тут:

```
if($i>=10)
    {
    return;
    }
```

**UPD:** Вместо глобального счетчика, для ограничения вложенности графа, есть смысл ввести в функцию дополнительный параметр `$level`

```
function molnia($point, $level){
    if( $level>=10 ) return; // Выход по счетчику

    // ... тут ваши расчеты точек...

    molnia($point1, $level+1); // 1-й рекурсивный вызов
    molnia($point2, $level+1); // 2-й рекурсивный вызов
}

molnia(array(0,0), 0); // Первый вызов
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну никогда не видел, чтобы рекурсия вызывалась сама в себе 2 раза ИМХО, как-то неправильно.

Нужно исправлять логику и понимание рекурсии, рекурсия сама в себе обычно вызывается только один раз.

```
global $i;
    if($i>=10)
        {
        return;
        }
    $i++;
```

Это работает? Нет я так просто спрашиваю, обычно условия и некоторые параметры лучше передавать в рекурсию повторно, проще и выгоднее потом найти ошибку.

```
molnia($k1);
molnia($k2);
```

Даже если рекурсия дойдет до второго вызова, заново будет вызван первый, тут очень похоже что сожрется вся память и ответ будет неверный и скрипт вылетит просто.

Comment: Формально говоря, двойной рекурсивный вызов некриминален, приведу классический пример (конечно, быстрее здесь построить треугольник Паскаля динамикой, но важен сам факт):

    С(n, k) = C(n - 1, k) + C(n - 1, k - 1)
    C(n, n) = C(n, 0) = 1

Другое дело, что автор намудрил, конечно.

Comment: в быстрой сортировке два рекурсивных вызова. обход бинарного дерева тоже два вызова делает. так что все ок. важнее конец рекурсии отследить.